# Winograd and Coppersmith Algorithm for fast matrix multiplication

Tags: algorithms

I have been trying to understand the algorithm given by Winograd and Coppersmith using Arithmetic Progressions (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/ramsey/matrixmult.pdf). I have been successful in understanding the basic idea of the algorithm. However, I fail to understand the combinatorics involved in the algorithm. 
For instance, On page 263, the paper talks about the number of blocks compatible with $Z^{[K]}$. Can anyone help me understand the same?

I also do not understand how does one decide the choice of $\beta$, the $L$ (page 262)? I am unable to reason these minute little details of the algorithm. I have tried looking at a number of different papers but I haven't been to find reasons for the steps involved in the above said algorithm.

Kindly, help me in this regard. Thanks!